# Question on the integer size

Tags: script, math

Is there any kind of boolean division with bitcoin?  There has to be something before the decimal number.  Kind of say it seems like end to end and it always should be the number that is largest.

Comment: What do you mean by boolean division?

Answer (score 1):

> **Question on the integer size**

Bitcoin uses many sizes of integer from 8-bit integers up to at least 256-bit integers. It also has variable-size integers. It uses a mix of signed and unsigned integers.

> **Is there any kind of boolean division with bitcoin?**

There is no kind of division at all *in Bitcoin scripting language* since `OP_DIV` and `OP_2DIV` were disabled.

I imagine fairly normal division is involved in calculating network difficulty and in calculating network time for checking block timestamps.

> **There has to be something before the decimal number.**

The Bitcoin *network* probably doesn't have significant use for decimal numbers.

Units of money are integer Satoshi. There are 100,000,000 Satoshi per Bitcoin. The user interface of software sometimes converts money in integer Satoshis to some decimal unit such as Bitcoin or millibitcoin for user-interface purposes only. Internally it is all integers.

Hashes and signatures are mainly working with large integers so far as I know.

The compressed "bits" representation of network difficulty bears some superficial resemblance to floating point number representation but nothing else decimal-like occurs to me.